# In a SVC classifier, once i changed the kernel from rbf (non-linear) to linear, performance improved massively. How can this be explained?

Tags: machine-learning

Accuracy stayed the same but F1 score went from 0.0 to 0.5, ROC-AUC from 0.0 to 0.7 (with non-linear activation the classifier predicted everything to be 0).

Isnt non-linear always more precise than linear, just more demanding computatinally? Linear separable classes can be separated just as well with a non-linear activation right? Its just that the opposite cant happen (non-linear classes cant be separable with linear activation).

So how can it be explained what i wrote in the title?